# NODE JS Cannot GET / Error Occurs Cant be fixed

Tags: node.js, api

This is my NODEJS API that gets data Through MSSQL, the problem is that it's not working!

```
import express from "express";
var app = express();
var port = process.env.port || 1337;


var dbConfig = {
    server:'123.123.12.1,1443',
    database:'testingDB',
    user:'userName',
    password:'pass',
    port:1433
};
```

***EDIT***
I answer my own Question and you just simply don't need to put Port in connection String. That's it.

Comment: how are you calling this API ?

Comment: I am calling it through postman

Comment: what is the url that you are hitting in postman ?

Comment: Its localhost:1337/product

Comment: do you see any error when you run your server ? I mean something like `node fileName` etc ?

Comment: This error cannot GET/product

Comment: I think he means error in your console or gitbash as oppose to browser. Usually Cannot GET/product appears in browser

Comment: There was couple of error in that thanks

Comment: I never saw the console. I am very new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pretty Easy to fix this problem. 
Its basically you don't need to write port in the connection string. if you do it will give connection error.
if you are a newbie like me make sure to use console logs.